# Proof that $\{x \}$ is nowhere dense if and only if $x$ is not an isolated point of $X$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

The following is a proof of the result in the title of the question.
I am writing it for various reasons, in particular to check if the proof is indeed correct, and to get a feedback on my writing skills.

> **Proposition:** $\{x \}$ is nowhere dense if and only if $x$ is not an isolated point of $X$.
>
> *Proof:*
>   $[\Rightarrow]$ Assume that int(cl($\{ x \})) = \varnothing$. Thus, $X \neq \{ x \}$ and the result trivially holds.
>   $[\Leftarrow]$ Assume that $x$ is not an isolated point of $X$. Thus,
>   for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon (x) \cap X \neq \varnothing$.
>   Hence, $X$ is not a singleton. To prove that int(cl($\{ x \})) =
>  \varnothing$, notice that it is the same to prove cl($ X \setminus \{
>  x \}) = X$. Thus, let $y \in M$ be arbitrary. We have to prove that, for
>   every $\epsilon>0$, $B_\epsilon (x) \cap (X \setminus \{ x \}) \neq
>  \varnothing$, but this holds trivially if $X$ is not a singleton.
>   Hence, the result is established. **QED**

Any feedback is most welcome!

Comment: You seem confused about the meaning of the terms involved. Nothing in the question or the argument should be about whether or not $X$ is a singleton, that is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo: First of all, thanks for your feedback. Thus, is the "proof" completely wrong? Could you please tell me what is a wrong inferential step? Just because to me they looked - and still look - ok, thus I cannot do anything particularly useful with the feedback as it stands. :)

Comment: Yes, both directions of the proof are completely wrong. Begin by looking up the right definition of "isolated point" and make sure to include it explicitly.

Comment: My line of reasoning was that $x$ is not an isolated point, thus it is *a fortiori* a **limit point**. Indeed, the definition of limit point says that $x \in X$ is a limit point of a set $A \subseteq X$ iff for every $\epsilon >0$, $(B_\epsilon (x)\setminus \{x \} ) \cap A \neq \varnothing$.  Then, an **isolated point** of a set $A \subseteq X$ is a point $x \in A$ that it is not a limit point of $A$.

Comment: In this case, taking the previous definitions, $A = X$ and the result to be proven should be int(cl($\{x\}) = \varnothing \Longleftrightarrow \forall \epsilon > 0 ( B_\epsilon (x) \setminus \{x \} ) \cap X \neq \varnothing)$.

Comment: Of course, I am not writing down all those things to "convince" you. :D It is just to show what was my line of reasoning, and how I was actually fairly confident to have followed the definitions. Actually, I still don't see where I went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I’ll give a fairly detailed commentary on your argument.

> $[\Rightarrow]$ Assume that int(cl($\{ x \})) = \varnothing$. Thus, $X \neq \{ x \}$ and the result trivially holds.

It’s true that if $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\{x\}=\varnothing$, then $X\ne\{x\}$, but this by no means implies that $x$ is not an isolated point. For a simple counterexample, note that $\Bbb Z\ne\{0\}$, but $0$ certainly *is* an isolated point of $\Bbb Z$. The simplest approach here is to prove the contrapositive: assume that $x$ is an isolated point, and show that $\{x\}$ is *not* nowhere dense. This actually is trivial: if $x$ is isolated, then $\{x\}$ is an open subset of $\operatorname{cl}\{x\}$, so $\operatorname{int}\operatorname{cl}\{x\}\ne\varnothing$.

> $[\Leftarrow]$ Assume that $x$ is not an isolated point of $X$. Thus,
>   for every $\epsilon > 0$, $B_\epsilon (x) \cap X \neq \varnothing$.

$B_\epsilon(x)\cap X\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$ even if $x$ *is* an isolated point of $X$. What you want here is that $B_\epsilon(x)\cap\big(X\setminus\{x\}\big)\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$.

> Hence, $X$ is not a singleton. 
>   To prove that int(cl($\{ x \})) =
>  \varnothing$, notice that it is the same to prove cl($ X \setminus \{
>  x \}) = X$. Thus, let $y \in M$ be arbitrary.

I assume that $M$ is a typo for $X$.

> We have to prove that, for
>   every $\epsilon>0$, $B_\epsilon (x) \cap (X \setminus \{ x \}) \neq
>  \varnothing$,

No, you have to show that $B_\epsilon(y)\cap\big(X\setminus\{x\}\big)\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$.

> but this holds trivially if $X$ is not a singleton.

This is sufficiently lacking in detail that I can’t tell whether you have in mind a correct argument or not; you need to expand it a bit. Something like this would do:

> If $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, then obviously $y\in B_\epsilon(y)\cap\big(X\setminus\{x\}\big)\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$, and by hypothesis $B_\epsilon(x)\cap\big(X\setminus\{x\}\big)\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$, so $B_\epsilon(y)\cap\big(X\setminus\{x\}\big)\ne\varnothing$ for each $\epsilon>0$, and $\operatorname{cl}\big(X\setminus\{x\}\big)=X$, as desired.

Comment: First of all something mundane: let me say that this answer is absolutely brilliant, and I was seriously thinking to put a bounty on this question because it is on a topic that is fairly important, *and* that it is obvious I don't understand properly.

Comment: Regarding the answer, one point here, and two questions shortly after, to be sure I see what's going on. Yes, indeed $M$ is a typo, and also the $x$ in $B \in (x) \cap (X \setminus \{x\}) \neq \varnothing$ is a typo (true, far more dangerous).

Comment: Regarding the questions, the first is about the fact that you write "if $x$ is isolated, then $\{x\}$ is an open subset of cl$\{x\}$". Honestly, I am not sure I do see why this is the case: the definition of open set says that a set $A$ is open iff for every $x \in A$, there is a $\epsilon >0$ s.t. $B_\epsilon (x) \subseteq A$. What is the $\epsilon$ that does the job here? True, we have only one $x$ and it has to be $x \in \{ x \}$, but what is the $\epsilon >0$ that works? Is this actually an occurence of something that is true *vacously*?

Comment: @Kolmin: By definition a point $x$ is isolated if and only if $\{x\}$ is an open set. In the metric setting this means that $x$ is an isolated point if and only if there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x)=\{x\}$.

Comment: The second question concerns the strategy behind the sufficient condition. Thus, is it actually a correct strategy, assuming that I completed the proof with the last step you wrote down (that I thought was obvious and could be avoided)? Again, really thanks a lot, that was purely brilliant, and – small aside – happy new year!

Comment: @Kolmin: Yes, with the changes that I suggested it becomes a perfectly fine proof of the implication in that direction.

Comment: Thus, regarding the isolated point definition, being an isolated point implies that the singleton with that element is an open set. But in general a singleton needs not be an open set. Quite the contrary, based on what I wrote down in my previous comment, right? I think this is what was making me confused.

Comment: @Kolmin: That’s right: a singleton can be open or not, depending on the space. For example, every singleton in $\Bbb Z$ is open, but no singleton in $\Bbb R$ is open. In the subspace $\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}$ of $\Bbb R$, every singleton except $\{0\}$ is open.

Comment: I know it shouldn't be done in a comment, but this very time I will do it and I will add a completely unuseful - from a mathematical point of view - comment, because that was great! Thanks really a lot, and again whatever time zone you are in happy new year

Comment: @Kolmin: You’re very welcome, and the same to you!